# Swapping last occurrence of min & max in array

Tags: c

I'm currently trying to swap the position of the min & max of an array using pointers.

```
(a) Single instance min & max
Input: 1 2 3 4 5
Output: 5 2 3 4 1

(b) Multiple instance min & max
Input: 9 1 1 9 9 5 5 5 5 
Output: 9 1 9 9 1 5 5 5 5
```

Code:

```
void swapMinMax(int ar[], int size)
{
int i, *max, *min;

*max = *min = ar[0];
//swap max & min
for(i=0;i<size-1;i++)
{
    if(ar[i]>*max)
        *max=ar[i];
    else if(ar[i]<*min)
        *min=ar[i];
}
}
```

How do I implement the swap for multiple instances of min & max?

Comment: @Qubit Question says switching the last occurrence of min and max and the example shows the same.

Comment: @kiranBiradar Yeah, I just noticed that *last* in the title, but not in the body. Anyway, if that's the case then all you need to do is change your `if` statement from strictly larger/smaller to large/smaller or equal to and do the same thing you do for the case where they only appear once. That way you'll grab the last occurrence. But you still have to implement the switching and there are some bugs in your code as it is right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To grab the last occurrence of the minimal and maximal values you simply have to change your if statement from strictly larger/smaller to larger/smaller or equal to, that way it will grab the last.

Before you can do that however, you need to fix some of the other problems in your code.

First of, you create `min` and `max` as pointers, but then attempt to use them to store values, this will cause undefined behaviour (your program probably won't work).

Second, if `size` is the size of your array, then, for some reason, you skip the last element.

And lastly, you still need to swap the elements in the end.

Combining all this, we get:

```
void swapMinMax (int ar[], int size) {
    int i, *max, *min;
    max = min = ar;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) { //Iterate over the entire array
        if (ar[i] >= *max) //Larger or equal to since we want the last occurrence
            max = &ar[i]; //Assign a pointer to our pointer
        else if (ar[i] <= *min) //Smaller or equal to since we want the last occurrence
            min = &ar[i]; //Again, we assign a pointer to our pointer
        }
    }
    //And now we swap the values
    int temp = *min;
    *min = *max;
    *max = temp;
}
```